# xkeyval error when using the changes package

Tags: errors, xkeyval, changes

I am working on an Analysis textbook with a friend, and am using the changes package, but keep getting the following error:

```
Package xkeyval Error: `remark' undefined in families `Changes@added'. ... \added[id=MD,remark={we need this}]{new}
```

Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[left=1.65cm,right=1.65cm,top=2.45cm,bottom=2.60cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amsbsy,array,color,pxfonts,latexsym,multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem,pstricks,framed} 
\usepackage[amsmath,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\setenumerate[1]{label=(\alph*)}
\setenumerate[2]{label=(\roman*)}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\newcommand{\NOT}{\sim}\newcommand{\AND}{\wedge}\newcommand{\OR}{\vee}
\newcommand{\twolinebrace}{\rlap{$\smash{\raisebox{.5\height}{\bigg\}}}$}}
\newlength{\LHS}\newlength{\RHS}
\settowidth{\LHS}{$P \OR (Q \OR R)$}\settowidth{\RHS}{$(P \AND Q) \OR (P \AND R)$}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}p{\LHS}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{$}p{\RHS}<{$}}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{lipsum}% <- For dummy text
\definechangesauthor[name={Croix Snapp}, color=red]{CS}
\definechangesauthor[name={Michael Dykes}, color=blue]{MD}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% Equation Numbering %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
%code by Heiko Oberdiek
\makeatletter
%Roman counter
\newcounter{roem}
\renewcommand{\theroem}{\roman{roem}}

% save the original counter
\newcommand{\c@org@eq}{}
\let\c@org@eq\c@equation
\newcommand{\org@theeq}{}
\let\org@theeq\theequation

%\setroem sets roman counting
\newcommand{\setroem}{
    \let\c@equation\c@roem
    \let\theequation\theroem}

%\setarab the arabic counting
\newcommand{\setarab}{
    \let\c@equation\c@org@eq
    \let\theequation\org@theeq}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% Page Commands %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\newcommand \np{\newpage}
\newcommand \q{\quad}
\newcommand \qq{\qquad}
\newcommand \qqq{\quad\quad\quad}
\newcommand \qqqqq{\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% Sets used in Analysis %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
\def    \bN{\mathbb N}
\def    \bZ{\mathbb Z}
\def    \bQ{\mathbb Q}
\def    \bR{\mathbb R}
\def    \bC{\mathbb C}
\def    \bp{\mathbb P}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% Mathematical Notation %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %   

\newcommand{\eqdefn}{%
    \ensuremath{\mathrel{\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}}}}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{:=}
\newcommand{\defeq}{=:}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
\newcommand{\card}[1]{\overline{\overline{#1}}}

\newcommand         \inj{\rightarrowtail }
\newcommand         \sur{\twoheadrightarrow }
\newcommand         \bij{\longleftrightarrow}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

%opening
\title{Analysis}
\author{Croix Snapp, and Michael Dykes}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Logic, Set Theory, Functions, and Relations.}
\section{Mathematical Logic.}
\subsection*{Introduction.}
\small{Analysis is all about the theory behind Calculus. In this course, we do not take for granted such notions as what the set $\bR$ of real numbers is; rather we carefully define $\bR$ by ``building" it out of other sets - beginning with the set $\bN$ of Natural Numbers. Numbers and number systems (i.e. $\bN, \bZ, \bQ, \bR$, and $\bC$) are the ``building-blocks" of Analysis. Here in this book, we do not merely state the properties of the Real Number System, but we derive them. 

However, This is \added[id=MD,remark={we need this}]{new} this introductory chapter - Chapter 0 - in order to give the reader the tools needed to carry on this study of the branch of mathematics known as Analysis. Here, we present a ``brief" review of Mathematical Logic, Set Theory, Functions, and Relations; and we ``informally" define a few sets of which we shall make frequent use of in Analysis. All of them (or most of them) shall be dealt with more formally in the next chapter.}



\end{document}
```

I am not sure how to get rid of this error. I have tried to see if my syntax for the changes package is incorrect, but so far no go.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's an error from `remark=` I see no mention of such a key in the changes package doc? Unrelated but `\small` does not take an argument so it should be `\small  Analysis...` not `\small{...}`

Comment: did you intend the documented `comment=` key?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `remark` key provided by [`changes`](//ctan.org/pkg/changes). Instead, use the `comment` key to add remarks.

```
\added[id=<id>,comment=<comment>]{<stuff>}
```